# Restrict Viewer Access to Cloud Storage Objects via ACL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, access-control-list, google-cloud-storage

I'm hosting a static site in a Cloud Storage Bucket with fine-grained permissions set. I'm attempting to set by-object ACL permissions so users can only access specific resources if they have a whitelisted email address (not necessarily google) or some other identifier such as a unique access URL.

However, I cannot determine how to obtain a URL for an object without granting access to `allUsers` or `allAuthenticatedUsers`, which in turn defeats my ACL. Is there a way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are hosting static files on Cloud Storage, it is expected that your files must be [accessible publicly](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#access_to_public_objects). If the objects are private and you used the URI `storage.googleapis.com`, you will get an access denied error. This has an ongoing [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/187005607).

In order to authenticate your users when accessing a GCS object, you must use the URI `storage.cloud.google.com` and they must use a Google Account. If not, then you can generate a [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) so they can view the object.

Additional Reference:

https://jbrojbrojbro.medium.com/controlling-access-to-google-cloud-storage-edf639464fea